# AngularJs Injecting template html in a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, css

I have to simulate a functionality of slider , it has some controls like **next / prev button and a toggle fullscreen button**. On toogle fullscreen , I have to show the slider in stretched mode , I have done this using z-index but it is not working, since parent of slider has lower z-index than that of its siblings . you can see implementation here

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/22326/

```
<div id="slide"  ng-class ='{fullscreen:isFullScreen}'   
     style="background : #FFEB3B;padding: 20px; margin:10px;" >
  content of page {{currentPageNo}}
    <div class="control">
        <button ng-click="nextPage();">Next Page</button>
        <button ng-click="isFullScreen = !isFullScreen;">Toggle Full Screen</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

- One possible solution is to change z-index of slider parent and its
  sibling using javascript.
- Other possible  solution is to prepend a
  div container in body and inject slider html in that container. But I
  don't know how I can do this in angular

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the `z-index` css property better. Issue was the `z-index` of the fullscreen element is relative to its parent and its parent has the lower value of `z-index` from the sibling one so that was the issue. Check the snippet below:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.currentPageNo = 1;
  $scope.nextPage = function() {
    $scope.currentPageNo++;
  }


})
```

```css
.fullscreen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 3; /*<------has the highest property*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div style="background : #f00; margin:10px; position:relative; z-index : 1">
    <!----------------------------------------------check above--^^^^^^^^^^^-->
    Parent sibling Content
    <br/>Parent sibling Content
    <br/>
  </div>

  <div style="background :  #4CAF50;margin:10px; position:relative; z-index :2">
    <!-----------------------------------------------check above--^^^^^^^^^^^-->
    Parent Content
    <br/>Parent Content
    <br/>

    <div id="slide" ng-class='{fullscreen:isFullScreen}' style="background : #FFEB3B;padding: 20px; margin:10px;">
      content of page {{currentPageNo}}
      <div class="control">
        <button ng-click="nextPage();">Next Page</button>
        <button ng-click="isFullScreen = !isFullScreen;">Toggle Full Screen</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    Parent Content
    <br/>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but I am working on a website which has already created and changing z-index of other html element ( expect slider element which is new functionality) results in broken ui at different other places . so maximum I can do is change zindex on full screen mode and revert change in zindez on normal mode.

Comment: @DurGeshkuMarRAO Yes That is what you can do for sure, but you need to store the old value somewhere so that you can refer it again to revertback. although you can override the position property for better.

Comment: Can you share your idea , how to store the old values as I have to take care of header, footer, slidebar , top nav bar and many more . Also the slider template will be displayed on different pages like home page , single activity page , group page etc.  Is there any generic way to solve this problem using jquery/javascript.